# PHP class constants seems to always be interpreted as strings

Tags: php, type-conversion, class-constants

A class constant always seems to be interpreted as a string although it is defined as an integer. Why does PHP do this kind of type juggling and how do I prevent it?

See the following code:

```php
class BitSet {
  const NONE = 0;
  const FOO = 1;
  const BAR = 2;
  const ALL = 3;

  public function __construct( $flags = self::NONE ) {
    if( $flags & self::ALL !== $flags )
      throw new \OutOfRangeException( '$flags = '.$flags.' is out of range' );
    $this->value = $flags;
  }

  protected $value = self::NONE;
}

$bs = new BitSet( BitSet::FOO );
```

The last line (the invocation of the constructor) throws the `OutOfRangeException`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'OutOfRangeException' with message '$flags = 1 is out of range' in test-case.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/matthiasn/class-constant-debug.php(19): BitSet->__construct('1')
#1 {main}
thrown in /srv/www/matthiasn/class-constant-debug.php on line 12
```

As you can clearly see from backtrace entry #0 the constant `BitSet::FOO` is passed as a character not as an integer. Hence, the bit mask operation `$flags & self::ALL !== $flags` is not performed on integers but on the bitwise ASCII representation and therefore fails.

What the hell?! Is there any better way to get this right than to do an explicit `(int)`-cast everywhere?

Comment: Don't you think `if( $flags &` `<-------`needs to be `&&`

Comment: @Uchiha No, it's a bitwise AND operation. It means "produce a value with bits set to 1 if they are 1 in both operands, 0 otherwise".

Comment: I'm not sure why the stack trace looks like that, but var_dump shows it as an int: http://3v4l.org/mEYRZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you expect, but note that `!==` has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `&` so you are doing a bitwise AND between `1` and `true`.

Do you perhaps mean:

```
if( ($flags & self::ALL) !== $flags )
```

Comment: Yes, this it was. See my own solution. I found that out, half a minute after a posted this question. PHP is ...

Comment: @user2690527 Yes, I figured that that was the problem so I replaced my comment with an answer.

Comment: The intention of the code seems pretty clear to me. I guess if you know the operator precedence by heart, the code seems obviously wrong, but it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was my fault and I went into the wrong direction. The solution is

```
if( ( $flags & self::ALL ) !== $flags )
```

to add parentheses. The `!==` operator seems to have a higher priority than `&`.

Without the parantheses, first the snippet `self::ALL !== $flags` is evaluated to `FALSE` and then `$flags & FALSE` is evaluated.

PHP is ... :-(

Comment: PHP is ... doing exactly the same thing as other languages here.

Comment: How sweet, it's the fault of the language and not the guy in the chair. Because that's apparently how IT works.